# Alerting user that the app still uses Location Updates (GPS)

Tags: ios, ios8, gps, core-location, cllocationmanager

Some apps, including the apple maps or some navigation apps are alerting the user with a kind of blue alert stripe if you send the app to background, that the app still uses the GPS (LocationUpdates)

Is there a public api or way to do this automatically or should it be programmed using the notification that the app will go to background.

I appreciate any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS8 and later `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` puts up the blue bar. It's put up by Apple to remind the user of the device that the app is using CoreLocations.

On the other hand if you use `requestAlwaysAuthorization` blue bar wont' show, but Apple will periodically remind users that your app is using location and seek their permission.

Comment: Thanks, I was using the requestAlwaysAuthorization and therefore the system never show me the blue stripe. However, I also never seen the "seeking permissions" except the first ever one. Thereafter, there were no more asking permission

Comment: @i-developer glad to be of help. Happy Coding. :D